# charAt() function in JOLT for strings to pull a character based on position

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I'm getting `null` in the output for the below.

Spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "f($;$ = $.A.charAt(2)  )": "charAt"
    }
  }
]
```

Input:

```json
[
  {
    "A": "Active"
  }
]
```

Expected Output:

```json
{
  "charAt": "t"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such function called ***charAt***, in addition the functions cannot be used within a **shift** transformation.

You rather can use a **modify** transformation spec along with ***elementAt*** function such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "A": "=split('',@(1,&))", // convert the string into an array of letters which constructs it
        "charAt": "=elementAt(2,@(1,A))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "A": "" // get rid of the reformed array
      }
    }
  }
]
```

which will return the letter **`t`** from the literal **`A`** with the index **`2`** whenever index starts from **`0`**

The ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Best wishes @Alexa